group by order/priority based on separate column
Given a table such as



id
name
city
priority
updated




1
isaac
mars
1
TIMESTAMP


2
asimov
paris
0
TIMESTAMP


3
jake
york
1
TIMESTAMP



I want to fetch a number of items, 1 per city/name combination, and prioritize/ensure that rows with priority are included in the result. After handling priority the "oldest" row would be selected
For example, in the table above, it would be expected to fetch ids 1 and 3 if we fetch 2 rows. If we fetch 3 rows instead of 2, then id 2 would be included as well (we start by getting priority rows, and fill out with non priority rows if we have room)
Im trying with a query like
select any_value(id) keep(dense_rank first order by priority, updated) from table group by city, name fetch next 2 rows only

but have trouble with the priority aspect. A possible solution could be to go for a join of two different selects, one to get priority rows and one to get non priority (given bandwidth) but that seems like fairly convoluted and inefficient approach and would probably not scale well as the database grow

To get only one row per name,city combination and ensure you pick the right ones based on priority, you just need a simple analytic function that uses both a compound partition by and a compound order by clause.
But then to rank the name,city combinations in order to get the "top N" results, you need another analytic function without a partition by clause against the results of the preceding step by nesting your query blocks:
select *
  from (
        select x.*,
               row_number() over (order by priority desc, updated) seq2
          from (select x.*,
                       row_number() over (partition by name,city order by priority desc, updated) seq
                  from mytable x) x
         where seq = 1) x
 where seq2 <= 2

The same thing could be done multiple ways with various analytical functions. This is just one way.

Tried around a bit, and came to this:
with prioritized as (select id, city, name from table where priority = 1)
select id from prioritized
UNION ALL -- UNION alone sorts the output
select distinct first_value(id) over (partition by name, city order by updated asc)
from table
where priority = 0
and (city, name) not in (select city, name from prioritized)

I tried this with SQLite, but i think this also matches the oracle syntax.
Usually oracle is pretty good at optimizing queries like these, but before trying to apply magic, you could check if this does what you want to do and if the explain plan makes it seem like optimizing is necessary
